# Liferay Commerce: Is there any event is thrown when Product Quantity Change on Mini Cart?

Tags: liferay, product-quantity, minicart, liferay-commerce

I am working with Liferay DXP 7.3 and Commerce 3.0. (GA1)

After add product to Cart, I change product quantity and I would like to listen this event.

Is there any event is thrown in this case?
How can I listen to it?

[image: [mini-cart-image]]

Answer (score 2):

The component refreshes itself by using this useEffect.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        Liferay.on(CURRENT_ORDER_UPDATED, updateCartModel);

        return () => {
            Liferay.detach(CURRENT_ORDER_UPDATED, updateCartModel);
        };
    }, [updateCartModel]);
```

Where `CURRENT_ORDER_UPDATED` === `'current-order-updated'`

Try something like the one below to better investigate

```
Liferay.on('current-order-updated', console.log)
```

Comment: Hi @Fabio, thank you for your answer. With LR DXP 7.3 and Commerce 3.0 (GA1). I can not find 'current-order-update', only available CHANGE_ORDER = 'orderSelected', but this event is not throw in this case